# Error in QBasicTimer.start()

Tags: python, timer, pyqt, typeerror

I am getting an error in this line:  `self.timer.start(100, self)`.

The type of the error is:

> TypeError: QBasicTimer.start(int, QObject): argument 2 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

I tried to change `self.timer.start(100, self)` to `self.timer.start(100, "Ui_MainWindow")` but it still shows errors.

Code Main:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from editorFrame import Ui_MainWindow

class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Editor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code editorFrame:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.rnd = 0
        self.segS = 0
        self.segA = 0
        self.count = 0

        self._start = 0.0
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self.timer = QBasicTimer()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.simulacion)


    def simulacion(self):
        self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
        self._running = 1
        self.timer.start(100, self)          

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        elap = time.time() - self._start
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)
        self.label.setText('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))
        self.segS = int(elap)


    def _setTime(self, elap):
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        seconds = int(elap - minutes*60.0)
        hseconds = int((elap - minutes*60.0 - seconds)*100)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Practica 4", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Empezar", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "00:00:00", None))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental mistake you are making is to edit the file generated by `pyuic`. Do not **ever** do this. It's a static module that is meant to be imported at runtime. Put **all** of your program logic in the main file.

The reason why you are getting that error is because `Ui_MainWindow` is just a simple namespace class. It is only meant to be used for adding the widgets from Qt Designer to your main window class (i.e. `Editor`).

You should also avoid using `QBasicTimer` with `timerEvent`, and use `QTimer` with signals instead:

```
class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        ...
        self._start = 0.0
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.handleTimer)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.simulacion)

    def simulacion(self):
        ...
        self.timer.start(100)          

    def handleTimer(self):
        elap = time.time() - self._start
        minutes = int(elap/60)
        ...

    def _setTime(self, elap):
        ...
```